# Magento2: Image Upload with Preview and Delete checkbox in Edit Admin Form

Tags: magento2

I am learning Magento2 and while developing module i got stuck and need help in below 2 points.

1) I have created admin form with Image upload functionality and its working perfectly.
but i want to display image  in edit form when image is saved.
So how to achieve that.

2) Also i want to know how to show image delete checkbox in edit form.

**Note: please note that i have created admin form using layout method not 
ui-component.**

code screen shots are attached. any help would be very appreciable.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlga2.png [code snippet ]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5nDH.png [expecting result like this, or any alternate way to achieve this]

Comment: The preview link and delete box should appear automatically if the image is saved correctly. check your save function and the location of the saved image.

Comment: Thanks for the clue @subroutine. 
But i found the issue. Issue was with the name of image field. 
i change name from image_url to image, its working.

But what if we have multiple images on same form, that time name should be unique, so how to handle in such case.

Comment: just give them different names and save them in your module's Adminhtml save controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can Add This

***Add this code into From creation file***

> ```
>     $fieldset->addField(
>         'image',
>         'image', 
>             array(
>                     'label'     => 'Image',
>                     'required'  => false,
>                     'name'      => 'image',  
>                     'note' => 'Allow image type: jpg, jpeg, png',      
>                     )
>     );
> ```

***Add This code into your Save From Data File***

> ```
> <?php
>
>
>   namespace [vendor_Name]\[Module_name]\Controller\Adminhtml\[controller_name];
>
>   use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
>   use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
>   use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
>   use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
>   use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
>   use Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory;
>
>
>   class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
>   {
>
>       protected $fileSystem;
>
>       protected $uploaderFactory;
>
>       protected $request;
>
>       protected $adapterFactory;
>
>
>       public function __construct(
>           \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
>           \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
>           \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
>           \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
>           AdapterFactory $adapterFactory
>       ) {
>           parent::__construct($context);
>           $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
>           $this->request = $request;
>           $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
>           $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
>       }
>
>       public function execute()
>       { 
>         $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
>
>
>         if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') 
>         {
>
>            try 
>              {    
>
>                $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);
>                $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
>                $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
>                $uploaderFactory->addValidateCallback('custom_image_upload',$imageAdapter,'validateUploadFile');
>                $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
>                $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
>
>                $mediaDirectory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
>                $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('[Folder_name]');
>
>
>                $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);
>
>
>                if (!$result) 
>                      {
>                        throw new LocalizedException
>                        (
>                           __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
>                        );
>
>                      }
>
>                $imagePath = '[Folder_Name]'.$result['file'];
>
>
>                $data['image'] = $imagePath;
>
>
>              } 
>              catch (\Exception $e) 
>             {   
>                  $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
>
>             }
>
>         } 
>
>       else
>         {     
>               $this->messageManager->addError(__("Image not Save Pleae Try Again")); 
>               $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
>               return;
>         }
>
>
>            if (!$data and $data['image'] == '') 
>             {    
>                 $this->messageManager->addError(__("Data Not Save Pleae Try Again")); 
>                 $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
>                 return;
>             }
>
>                 try {
>                         $rowData = $this->_objectManager->create('[vendor_Name]\[Module_name]\Model\locator');
>                         $rowData->setData($data);
>
>                         if (isset($data['id'])) 
>                         {
>                             $rowData->setId($data['id']);
>                             $rowData->setStoreImage($data['image']);
>                         }
>                         $rowData->save();
>
>                         $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Data has been successfully saved.'));
>                       } 
>                   catch (\Exception $e) 
>                       {
>                           $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
>                       }
>
>             $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
>
>
>
>
>           }
>
>
>       }
> ```

I Hope This Helps You.